# Prove a bijection and $D_{(2,0)}(f \circ g^{-1})$ as a matrix. Inverse functions

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the functions defined by: $$g(x,y):=(2ye^{2x},xe^y)$$ $$f(x,y):=(3x-y^2,2x+y,xy+y^3)$$

$a)$Show that there exists an open neighborhood $U$of $(0,1)\in \mathbb{R}^2$  and an open neighborhood $V$ of $(2,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $g:U \rightarrow V$ is a bijection.

$b$) Using standard Euclidean basis, express $D_{(2,0)}(f \circ g^{-1})$ as a matrix.

### My attempt

$a$)I was going to attempt to do a typical one-to-one proof and onto proof to show bijection but I don't think it's relevant in this case.

However, it seems like this problems involve the inverse function theorem. I know that if a function is bijective then its inverse exists (all though I am not sure if it is also true in the other direction).

What we know is that $(0,1)\in U$ and $(2,0)\in V$ and that $g$ is a function from $U$ to $V$.

I am not sure how to move on from here. Maybe find it's differential and see if the determinant $\neq 0$? Then what?

$b$) Not sure how to find $g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a), you can definitely use the inverse function theorem! This states that, if $g$ is differentiable with continuous derivatives, and the derivative $D g$ is an invertible matrix at a point $a$, then there exist open neighbourhoods $U$ of $a$ and $V$ of $g(a)$ such that $g: U \to V$ is invertible. Moreover, $g^{-1} : V \to U$ is also continuously differentiable, and the derivative of $g^{-1}$ at $g(a)$ is the matrix inverse of the derivative of $g$ at $a$:

$$ Dg^{-1}|_{g(a)} = (D g|_a)^{-1}.$$

If you compute $Dg|_a$ in your example, you will hopefully see that it *is* invertible at $a = (0,1)$. For example, you can check that its determinant is non-zero. So the inverse function theorem applies, providing the solution to part (a).

[Warning: I believe $g(a) = (2,0)$, not $(0,2)$, as you have written.]

For part (b), you can evaluate $D(f \circ g^{-1})|_{g(a)}$ using the chain rule:
$$ D(f \circ g^{-1})|_{g(a)} = Df|_{a} . Dg^{-1}|_{g(a)},$$
where the dot denotes matrix multiplication. You already know $Dg^{-1}|_{g(a)}$ from the inverse function theorem, so you just need to calculate $Df|_a$ and multiply the two matrices.

Comment: Question on notation. What does $|_{g(a)}$ mean?

Comment: $|_a$ means "evaluated at $a$". My $Dg|_a$ is the same as your $D_a g$.

Comment: Did I do this right?

$$[D_{(x,y)}g]=
\begin{bmatrix}
      4ye^{2x} & 2e^{2x} \\
     e^y & xe^y  \\
     \
      &  & 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Evaluated at $(0,1)$ the determinent does not equal $0$

Comment: And does this alone show that it's a bijection?

Comment: Yes, your derivative matrix looks right!

Comment: So you need to check (i) are the partial derivatives defined, and continuous, on an open neighbourhood of $(0,1)$? (yes, obviously, because they are products of polynomials and exponential functions); and (ii) is the determinant non-zero (yes!)

Comment: The conclusion you get from the theorem is that $g$ is a bijection LOCALLY. So there is a little open neighbourhood $U$ around $(0,1)$ that $g$ maps bijectively onto its image. This doesn't mean that $g$ is bijective on the whole of $\mathbb R^2$ - it's just a local statement!

Comment: Is $D_af$ evaluated at $(0,1)$ and $D_{g(a)}g^{-1}$ at $(2,0)$ ?

Comment: And for my first comment, shouldnt I have written instead: $$[D_{(x,y)}g]^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
      4ye^{2x} & 2e^{2x} \\
     e^y & xe^y  \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes, $D_a f$ is evaluated at $(0,1)$ and $D_{g(a)}g^{-1}$ is evaluated at $(2,0)$. Your expression for $D_{(x,y)}g$ and your expression for $D_{g(x,y)}g^{-1} = [D_{(x,y)}g]^{-1}$ are both correct.